# php code to replace a=1;b=2 and so on... using paramaterized function

Tags: php

I am  trying to replace a=1; b=2, c=3, z=26 like wise..for that i create a function..

But the below function shows me an error. What wrong with this code?

```
<?php
$str = "abc";
echo reverse($encoded);

function reverse($str)
{   
   $chars = array('a' => 1, 'b' =>  2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
   $encoded = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $encoded[] = $chars[$str[$i]];
    }

    return implode($encoded);
}
?>
```

Comment: *output and shows error* And what error do you get?

Comment: Would be easier to use something like [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr)`($str, "abcd", "1234")` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'$encoded' only exists inside your function..
Call your function with your '$str'.

```
$str = "abc";
echo reverse($str);
```

Comment: thanks for help i made silly mistake.......

Answer (score 2):

You pass `$encoded` at reverse but this variable is null, change it with `$str`.

```
$str = "abc";
echo reverse($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) turn on error display in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

2) you are sending $encoded instead of $str in to the function

3) next time try and do your own homework